# how to make the pattern to work with input number?

Tags: html

This is my first time using the `pattern` attribute. The following code is inside a `<form>` tag:

```
<input type="number" name=""  placeholder="Number" pattern=".{12,13}" required>
```

I expect the pattern to make the number has minimal of 12 numbers and a max of 13 numbers. However, I can still submit the form with less than 12 numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the `pattern` attribute on inputs of type `number`:

> `<input type="number">` elements do not support use of the pattern
>   attribute for making entered values conform to a specific regex
>   pattern. The rationale for this is that number inputs won't be valid
>   if they contain anything except numbers, and you can constrain the
>   minimum and maximum number of valid digits using the `min` and `max`
>   attributes
>
> [- MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#Pattern_validation)

As explained on MDN, you can use the `min` and `max` attributes to specify your domain:

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" name="number" placeholder="Number" min="100000000000" max="9999999999999" required />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Alternatively, you can use an `input` type of `text` (which does allow `pattern`), and match for digits (`\d`):

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="number" placeholder="Number" pattern="\d{12,13}" inputmode="numeric" title="Your number must be 12-13 digits long" required />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```